# What should be my models and actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm new to MVC and I've looked through a number of resources but not found any complete help so here's my understanding of what I'm trying to achieve:

I have a Model called 'Company' where each company will have a name, address, email and contact number.

I've been told this is a bit high-level as a model, something I don't really understand why..

As for my actions what should they be - add company, edit company, delete company? - Basically whatever actions are required by the user?

Comment: I'm even wondering if it's worth be going down the MVC route as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474641/why-should-i-use-an-mvc-framework-for-php

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problem. As always it depends on your scenario. If you are creating an app to manage companies, then your model seems ok to me. If you were a moving company, and moving companies from one place to another, maybe the Address can also be an entity in your model as it is part of your core and can contain more level of detail.

The same about the actions, add, edit, delete are good candidates. Controller receive these actions, modify the Model, and these changes are also reflected in the View.

MVC itself is a broad concept. Its meaning is more or less clear but it has been adapted to different kind of applications (i.e. web apps where it was often called [Model 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_2)).

Comment: Thanks for that..I sort of get the idea behind it. Similar to how CSS/HTML is used to separate content and styling I think...

Answer (score 0):

Inside the controller Company, If you need to add company details, Inside view place your target controller as "Company" and Action as "AddCompany".
By clicking on submit button, the control directly navigates to "AddCompany" Action inside, "Company" controller.

According to that you can add company details into database.

Similar scenario for Edit/Update/Delete company.

Regards,
Pavan.G

Answer (score 0):

Since your new to MVC and have not yet found any complete resource, i recommend you to watch Scott Allen`s videos on asp.net mvc 3 which start from the scratch and move up to the advanced level. It covers almost everything in MVC for beginners and should clear most of your doubts, here is the link below

http://pluralsight.com/training/courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspdotnet-mvc3-intro&highlight=scott-allen_mvc3-building-intro!scott-allen_mvc3-building-controllers!scott-allen_mvc3-building-security!scott-allen_mvc3-building-infrastructure!scott-allen_mvc3-building-ajax!scott-allen_mvc3-building-deploy!scott-allen_mvc3-building-views!scott-allen_mvc3-building-data-ii!scott-allen_mvc3-building-tdd!scott-allen_mvc3-building-data-i-2#mvc3-building-intro

Hope This helps!